# how to use getresourcepath() for relative path

Tags: java, filepath

Instead of `/asm/Hello.class`  it has to work for full path like `/home/lpl/eclipse/asm/bin/asm/Hello.class` please any one help me to solve this issue.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
 {
    InputStream in = Hello.class.getResourceAsStream("/asm/Hello.class");

    ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(in);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

    //Wrap the ClassWriter with our custom ClassVisitor
    ModifierClassWriter mcw = new ModifierClassWriter(Opcodes.ASM4, cw);
    classReader.accept(mcw, 0);

    //Write the output to a class file
    File outputDir = new File("bin/asm");
    outputDir.mkdirs();

    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputDir,"Hello.class")));

    dout.write(cw.toByteArray());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this for getting the absolute path to the file.

```
import java.io.File;


File temp = File.createTempFile("i-am-a-temp-file", ".tmp" );

String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
```